# iAd not working, in next version

Tags: iphone, ipad, iad

I m just curious to know, my current app is live and integrated with iAds.
iAds are working fine.

Now i m working on next release of the same app, and trying to implement iAds on other screens, but iAds(test ads) are not coming up.

Is it like, if the app is live and integrated with iAds, than test ads(also live ads) will not come up??

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only create one object of `iAd` in your application. If you want to display the ad on multiple screens you have to reference the single iAd to all the screens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That means, i should create one class with all the iAds methods, and than just call it at the classes where i want to show ads..right??

Comment: yes, or create one object and pass it to view controller where you want to display, then remove it and pass it to other view controller where you want to display after navigation.

Comment: but the thing is, i m not even getting ads which i integrated previously. So i was thinking, if the app is having live ads, i.e means they are active at iTunes.so will they reflect on my source code/simulator??

Comment: no, it should display test ad. check the console there must be some warning when you are showing iAd on a view controller.

Comment: Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Unknown error" UserInfo=0x980abb0 {ADInternalErrorCode=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unknown error}
this is the waring i m getting

Comment: check two thing, if your bannerview is properly configured specially delegate is set to the view controller, secondly if you tried logging error message in `- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error`

Comment: yes i did. also i got this error by using nslog in "- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error"

Comment: we sometime overcome this error by changing the time on the iPhone while testing iAd functionality.